# Doubly LinkedList Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, doubly-linked-list

This is a doubly linked list with sortedAdded and sortedRemove methods. When I run the code it throws "null point exception". I know the exception is at line "43" but I have no idea how to fix it. I went throw a post in this website on how to "prevent null point exceptions" but still couldn't make it right. Here is my code:

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item extends Comparable> {

private class Node{
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node getPrev(){
        return prev;
    }

    public Item getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void setPrev(Node prev){
        this.prev= prev;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item){
        this.item = item;
    }
}

private Node head;
private int numberOfEelements;

public void sortedAdd(Item newItem) {
    Node dummy = head;
    Node current = dummy.getNext();
    while ((newItem.compareTo(current.getItem()) > 0) && (current != dummy))
        current = current.getNext();
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.setNext(current);
    temp.setPrev(current.getPrev());
    (current.getPrev()).setNext(temp);
    current.setPrev(temp);
    temp.setItem(newItem);
    ++numberOfEelements;
}

public void sortedRemove(Item newItem) {
    Node dummy = head;
    Node current = dummy.getNext();
    while((newItem.compareTo(current.getItem()) !=0) && (current!= dummy))
        current = current.getNext();

    if (newItem.equals(current.getItem())) {
        (current.getPrev()).setNext(current.getNext());
        (current.getNext()).setPrev(current.getPrev());
        --numberOfEelements;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();

        list.sortedAdd(1);
        list.sortedAdd(5);
        list.sortedAdd(7);
        list.sortedAdd(9);
        list.sortedAdd(3);
        list.sortedAdd(2);

        System.out.println(list);

        list.sortedRemove(3);
        list.sortedRemove(7);

        System.out.println(list);

        list.sortedRemove(4);
}
}
```

and here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DoublyLinkedList.sortedAdd(DoublyLinkedList.java:43)
    at DoublyLinkedList.main(DoublyLinkedList.java:74)
```

Comment: Point out the exact line that you're having the problem with, as there are no line numbers in the code you provided (and your line numbers are probably different than what we'd get if we copy and pasted it into an editor ourselves).

Comment: it is the 2nd line in sortedAdd method. ( Node current = dummy.getNext(); )

Comment: Before assign head to dummy check whether head is NULL or not

Comment: @Toni Check my answer on how you should add next and prev reference while creating the header in your new DoublyLinkedList

Answer (score 4):

In sortedAdd, you are not handling the initial case where head == null (which would mean an empty list in this case). Thus in the line `dummy.getNext();` you are calling getNext on a null reference.

Adding a check for a null head that creates one should get you past this error:

```
public void sortedAdd(Item newItem) {

    if (head == null) {
        head = new Node();
        head.setItem(newItem);
        ++numberOfEelements;
        return;
    }
```

Although you will hit another NPE a little further down due to your loop logic.

In order to print your list, you will need to add a toString() method:

```
public String toString(){
    Node current = head;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while(current != null){
        sb.append(current).append(" ");
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: i am trying to do that, but no idea how to do it. it would be appreciated if you can help more.

Comment: Just added a sample. Looking at your while loop, are you intending this list to be circular? If not, what's the intention of the statement: `(current != dummy)`?

Comment: i added a solution at the bottom, it prints something like this now.    DoublyLinkedList@3cd1a2f1    ...

Answer (score 1):

When an `Object` of type `DoublyLinkedList` is created using

```
DoublyLinkedList<Integer> list = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
```

`head` is initialized to `null` and `numberOfEelements` is initilaized to 0;

Add the following **`initializer`** in your `DoublyLinkedList` class

```
   {
         head = new Node();
         head.setNext(head);
         head.setPrev(head);
         head.setItem(null);
         numberOfEelements =0;
    }
```

---

```
public class DoublyLinkedList<Item extends Comparable> {    
    {
      head = new Node();
      head.setNext(head);
      head.setPrev(head);
      head.setItem(null);
      numberOfEelements =0;
    }
 private class Node{
    private Item item;
    private Node next;
    private Node prev;

    public Node getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public Node getPrev(){
        return prev;
    }

    public Item getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setNext(Node next) {
        this.next = next;
    }


    public void setPrev(Node prev){
        this.prev= prev;
    }

    public void setItem(Item item){
        this.item = item;
    }
}

private Node head;
private int numberOfEelements;

public void sortedAdd(Item newItem) {
    Node dummy = head;
    Node current = dummy.getNext();
    while ((newItem.compareTo(current.getItem()) > 0) && (current != dummy))
        current = current.getNext();
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.setNext(current);
    temp.setPrev(current.getPrev());
    (current.getPrev()).setNext(temp);
    current.setPrev(temp);
    temp.setItem(newItem);
    ++numberOfEelements;
}

public void sortedRemove(Item newItem) {
    Node dummy = head;
    Node current = dummy.getNext();
    while((newItem.compareTo(current.getItem()) !=0) && (current!= dummy))
        current = current.getNext();

    if (newItem.equals(current.getItem())) {
        (current.getPrev()).setNext(current.getNext());
        (current.getNext()).setPrev(current.getPrev());
        --numberOfEelements;
    }
}
```

Comment: i added a solution at the bottom, it prints something like this now.    DoublyLinkedList@3cd1a2f1    ...

Comment: You have to override 'toString' method to get desired output.

Comment: @pramithasdhakal i tried but couldnt get it working. how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when you are initializing head just after class Node ends - replace that initialization to: `private Node head=null;`

Now use the following code:

```
public void sortedAdd(Item newItem) {
    Node dummy = head;
    if(dummy==null)
    {
        head = new Node();
        head.setItem(newItem);
        head.setNext(null);
        head.setPrev(head);

    }
    else
    {
        Node current = dummy.getNext();
        while ((newItem.compareTo(current.getItem()) > 0) && (current != dummy))
            current = current.getNext();
        Node temp = new Node();
        temp.setNext(current);
        temp.setPrev(current.getPrev());
        (current.getPrev()).setNext(temp);
        current.setPrev(temp);
        temp.setItem(newItem);
    }
    ++numberOfEelements;

}
```

Comment: i added a solution at the bottom, it prints something like this now.    DoublyLinkedList@3cd1a2f1    ...